# Expo ImagePicker gets stuck on ActivityIndicator when canceled

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-application, react-native-image-picker

I'm creating a project where I need the user to pick an image from their Photo Gallery. However I've run into an issue where when the user cancels the ImagePicker while in their gallery, the Activity Indicator will show up and the user is no longer able to pick out an image. How can I do so that when the cancel button is pressed, the Upload image button will show back up?

Here is my code:

```
              {!this.state.loading ? (
                <Button
                  full
                  style={{
                    fontFamily: "nunito",
                    backgroundColor: "#f3d95c"
                    // alignSelf: "center",
                  }}
                  onPress={() => this.imagePicker()}
                >
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontFamily: "nunito"
                      // color: "white"
                    }}
                  >
                    {this.state.imageUrl === ""
                      ? "Upload Photo"
                      : "Photo Selected"}
                  </Text>
                </Button>
              ) : (
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
              )}
```

EDIT:Here is the function

```
imagePicker = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: false,
      base64: true
    }).then(async result => {
      const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
          resolve(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.onerror = function(e) {
          reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
        };
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.open("GET", result.uri, true);
        xhr.send(null);
      });

      const ref = firebase
        .storage()
        .ref()
        .child(uuid.v4());
      const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);
      blob.close();
      let imageUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

      this.setState({ imageUrl: imageUrl, loading: false });
    });
  };
```

Comment: You havbe  to change state of loading flag  in imagepicker function that you  didn't post. in then and finally or catch chain of Promise: this.setState({loading :false});

Comment: @Oleg oops, sorry. Edited